# Generate a TOC of sections under each chapter with DocBook/XSLT-FO

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop, docbook

I'm using FOP 2.3 and I have the following:

```
<book>
  <chapter>
    <title>ChA</title>
    <section>
      <title>Structures</title>
      <xi:include href="struct1.xml"/>
    </section>
    <section>
      <title>Functions</title>
      <xi:include href="function1.xml"/>
    </section>
  </chapter>
</book>
```

For `function1.xml` (as an example), I have:

```
<refentry xml:id="some_func" version="5.0">
  <refmeta>
    <refentrytitle>SomeFunc</refentrytitle>
  </refmeta>
  ...
</refentry>
```

Is it possible to...

1. Not list the sections between the `refentry`s, but to only list them under the chapter title as a mini ToC?
2. List the `refentry/refentrytitle` values under each section?

For example the output for the beginning of the chapter *ChA* should look like:

```
Page X
       ChA
         Structures
           SomeStruct
         Functions
           SomeFunc

Page X+1
       SomeStruct page

Page X+2
       SomeFunc page

Page X+3
       ChB
         Structures
           SomeStruct2
         Functions
           SomeFunc2
...
```

Next *new* page renders every `refentry` from all sections of chapter *ChA* sequentially, and are not broken up by sections *Structures* and *Functions*.

**Edit 1**

I was able to prevent the sections to be printed between the manual pages. I copied the `section.content` template:

```
<xsl:template name="section.content">
  <!-- Don't display section -->
  <!-- <xsl:call-template name="section.titlepage"/> -->
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

As for listing the sections, I found this:

```
<xsl:template match="chapter">
  ...
  <fo:page-sequence hyphenate="{$hyphenate}"
                    master-reference="{$master-reference}">
    ...
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <xsl:call-template name="set.flow.properties">
        <xsl:with-param name="element" select="local-name(.)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="master-reference" select="$master-reference"/>
      </xsl:call-template>

      <fo:block id="{$id}"
                xsl:use-attribute-sets="component.titlepage.properties">
        <xsl:call-template name="chapter.titlepage"/>
        <!-- === HERE IS WHERE I AM INSERTING MY CUSTOM TABLE OF CONTENTS === -->
        <xsl:for-each select="self::*/section">
          <fo:block>
            <xsl:message>DEBUG><xsl:value-of select="title"/></xsl:message>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>

            <xsl:for-each select="self::*/refentry/refmeta">
              <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="refentrytitle"/>
              </fo:block>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>

      </fo:block>

      <xsl:call-template name="make.component.tocs"/>

      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a while.

First, the `chapter` template has to be overwritten in your custom style file:

```
<xsl:template match="chapter">
  ...
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <xsl:call-template name="set.flow.properties">
        <xsl:with-param name="element" select="local-name(.)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="master-reference" select="$master-reference"/>
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="chapter.titlepage"/>

      <!-- Call Table of contents name here -->
      <xsl:call-template name="table.of.contents.titlepage.recto.sony"/>

      <fo:block id="{$id}" xsl:use-attribute-sets="component.titlepage.properties">
        <xsl:for-each select="self::*/section">
          <fo:block start-indent="{count(ancestor::*) + 2}pc">
            <xsl:variable name="section.id">
              <xsl:call-template name="object.id"/>
            </xsl:variable>

            <!-- XXX: Error if "title" element doesn't exist -->
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
          </fo:block>

          <!-- XXX: Error if "refnamediv" doesn't exist -->
          <xsl:for-each select="self::*/refentry/refnamediv">
            <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="toc.line.properties" start-indent="{count(ancestor::*) + 2}pc">
              <xsl:variable name="refname.id">
                <xsl:call-template name="object.id"/>
              </xsl:variable>

              <!-- XXX: Error if "refname" doesn't exist -->
              <fo:inline font-family="Courier" keep-with-next.within-line="always">
                <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{$refname.id}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="refname"/>
                </fo:basic-link>
              </fo:inline>

              <fo:inline keep-together.within-line="always">
                <fo:leader leader-pattern="space"
                           keep-with-next.within-line="always"/>
                <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{$id}">
                  <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="{$refname.id}"/>
                </fo:basic-link>
              </fo:inline>

            </fo:block>
          </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:for-each>
      </fo:block>

      <xsl:call-template name="make.component.tocs"/>

      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</xsl:template>
```

The above will display a per-chapter table of contents. The section needs to be omitted:

```
<xsl:template name="section.content">
  <!-- Don't display section -->
  <!-- <xsl:call-template name="section.titlepage"/> -->
  ...
</xsl:template>
```